# no desktop or functions after login

Tags: drivers, graphics

After restarting after the Ubuntu OS installation, the login screen came up and everything looked normal with the toolbar (functioning correctly) at the top.

But when I logged into to my account or as guest, I lost the toolbar and the icons. I have tried every suggestion I could find on how to reset, reinstall, restart unity.

I am starting to believe the problem is my display drivers. When trying to restart unity the first line usually says it cannot find my display or some sort of fault for the display.

The system I am working with is a Toshiba Techra M7 with an internal Nvidia quadro nvs 110M 128 MB video card.

How do I check my video drivers or install what I need from a terminal screen?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I ended up going in and installing the graphics drivers needed.

Comment: The command : - ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended - : was able to detect what driver was recommended. Installed it, and everything started working normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your system, follow these steps:

- At the login screen press Ctrl + Alt + F1
- Enter your username and password there.
- After logging in there, enter these commands:

  `sudo apt-get update`
  `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
  `sudo reboot`

That's it --  now you should see the desktop.

For the driver diagnosis from the command line, `try ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended` .

Here's the usage info for the`ubuntu-drivers` command:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers --help

usage: ubuntu-drivers [-h] [--package-list PATH] 

List/install driver packages for Ubuntu.

positional arguments:
              See below

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --package-list PATH  Create file with list of installed packages (in
                       autoinstall mode)

Available commands:
   debug: Print all available information and debug data about drivers.
   autoinstall: Install drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation.
   list: Show all driver packages which apply to the current system.
   devices: Show all devices which need drivers, and which packages apply to them.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this took care of my issue along with another command to check for the recommended drivers...